# "Topological Equivalence" of Double Torus and a Torus with another hole

Tags: general-topology, deformation-theory

I was letting my mind wander when I  came up with this interesting topological figure:

[image]

It's a torus with a hole punched through its side towards its center. I then tried to determine whether or not this figure is "topologically equivalent" (homeomorphic) to a double torus. I suspect that they aren't, but how do I prove this? Do I need to know a *lot* of topology to prove something like this?

To clarify: The torus is solid and the hole does not lead to the actual interior of the torus; it *does* have a "skin" connecting the surfaces of the torus on either side of the hole. For example, if you had a point next to the hole on the "outer ring" of the torus and a point next to a hole on the "inner ring", you could connect the two with a path going through the hole without going over the top or bottom of the torus.

Comment: Proving this rigorously would require some topology. Indeed, it is equivalent to a surface of genus 2, assuming that you mean "punctured" as "having a hole put in it, but not breaking any of the 'skin.'"

Comment: There is some ambiguity in how to interpret the picture. I can think of at least four possible interpretations, all of which give rise to different objects. Can you clarify 1) whether the torus is solid, 2) if not solid, whether the "hole" is only on the "outside" or also goes through to the "inside," and 3) if not solid and the hole goes through to the inside, whether, as Chickenmancer suggests, the "hole" has "skin" connecting the inside and outside?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the question - you're right, I did leave that a little bit too vague. The torus is solid and the hole does not lead to the actual interior of the torus; it *does* have skin. For example, if you had a point next to the hole on the "outer ring" of the torus and a point next to a hole on the "inner ring", you could connect the two with a path going through the hole without going over the top or bottom of the torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As I mentioned in a comment I think the picture is ambiguous. Below is one interpretation based on the OP's comment to a deleted answer that not all of you might be able to see.)

A punctured torus is [homotopy equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence) to what is called a bouquet of two circles (two circles meeting at a point): basically the idea is to keep making the hole bigger and bigger. This is not homotopy equivalent to a genus $2$ surface (and hence a punctured torus is not homotopy equivalent, and so not homeomorphic, to a genus $2$ surface); the two can be distinguished most simply by their [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic), although it takes some effort to prove that the Euler characteristic is a homotopy invariant depending on how it is defined.

Comment: I would think that the OP also meant a solid "double torus".